# If polynomial has complex zeros, find values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Polynomial is $z^4-4z^3+11z^2-14z+10$ and has zeros $a+bi$, $a-2bi$. $a$ and $b$ are real and we're meant to find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Also, we're meant to find all zeros of said polynomial over complex field and then put it into a form of the product between two quadratic equations.

Answer (score 2):

HINTS:
All your coefficients are real. So there is something to do with conjugate root theorem.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$z^4-4z^3+11z^2-14z+10=(z^2-2z+2)(z^2-2z+5)$$

Comment: I'm thinking if the question is trying to get us to find the roots first and only after that get the factors in the form $(z^2-2Re(z_1)z+|z_1|^2)(z^2-2Re(z_2)z+|z_2|^2)$